# mathML square root and factorial not support in html5

Tags: javascript, html, mathml

> this is my mathml code but it's not working html5.how i will solve this please help me

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mroot><mn>123</mn><mn>123123</mn></mroot></math>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Firefox 47; it will not work in Chrome or IE. This is the entire text of my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML5 with MathML</title>
</head>
<body><p>Here is some MathML...
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mroot><mn>123</mn><mn>123123</mn></mroot></math>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```